# Will reading in dim light damage my eyes?

Tags: light, pathophysiology

People keep saying that it is important to have adequate light when reading, because reading in dim light will damage your eyes. Is this true and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**
The consensus is that sub-optimal lighting does not permanently damage the eye.

**Background**
Sub-optimal lighting can create a sensation of having difficulty in focusing. It also decreases the rate of blinking and this possibly to discomfort from dry eyes. These complaints **do not persist**. The majority consensus in ophthalmology is that reading in dim light does not damage your eyes; **it is a myth**. Although it can cause eye strain with multiple temporary negative effects, it is unlikely to cause a permanent change to the function or structure of the eyes [(Vreeman & Caroll, 2007)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2151163/).

If you Google your question many credible sources outside the scientific literature seem to agree that it is a myth busted, including [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/eye-health/features/reading-in-dim-light), [ABC](http://www.webmd.com/eye-health/features/reading-in-dim-light) and [Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424127887323646604578404581544768850).

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Vreeman & Caroll, *BMJ* (2007); **335**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2151163/)</sub>

Comment: actually, there may be some scientific evidence related to dim light being related to myopia. See the [recent review article](http://www.nature.com/news/the-myopia-boom-1.17120) on nature.